# If the value of 'object' is 0 the 'level' input is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, css

**What I have to do is:**
When the value of 'object' is 0 the 'level' input is not displayed..

**What i have:**

```
input type="text" id="level"                                          
input type="text" id="object"
```

**What i came up with:**

```
var lvl = document.getElementById("level")
var ogg = document.getElementById("object")

if (ogg == 0) {
    lvl.style.display = 'none';

};
```

This is not working and I'm new to JavaScript so please, HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

`ogg` is just a html node you need to use `value` `property` of `ogg` to access `input` value

```
if ( ogg.value == 0) {
        lvl.style.display = 'none';

    };
```

Or If you want to check if value is equal to null or blank.

```
if (!ogg.value && ogg.value.trim() == "") {
    lvl.style.display = 'none';

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value of the input field using `.value` attribute like :

```
if (ogg.value == 0) {
    lvl.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`var ogg = document.getElementById("object")` gives you element. Use

`ogg.value` to get the value of input element

Moreover

You get the value as string from input element so

Using `==` would do what you want but if you really take input as an `integer` or `number` you better parse it to `int` like

`var value = parseInt(ogg.value)`

And now use it in if condition like

```
if(value === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
var ogg = document.getElementById("object").value;
```

.value is used to access the text value from the html element.
Any more questions?

More info:**[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.as)**

So you can also change the text value of an element with .value

```
document.getElementById("myOption").value = "newValue";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the value of `object` on `keyup event`. Below is the working sample

```js
var lvl = document.getElementById("level")
var ogg = document.getElementById("object")

function check(){
  if (parseInt(ogg.value) === 0) {
      lvl.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
      lvl.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="level" placeholder="level">
<input type="text" id="object"  placeholder="object" onkeyup="check()">
```